# Ubuntu Folder shows full but it is empty

Tags: command-line, server, disk-usage

I have seen similar questions but not exactly what I am experiencing and no formidable answers.

I setup a virtual machine with Ubuntu Server 16.04. I setup `/var/www/html` as a share and share it with my Windows Host.

I dumped all my php scripts and projects into this folder and it works perfectly as a web server but the space ran up rather quickly.

I eventually deleted all the PHP after making a backup but the space shows that it is now full, even though `/var/www/html` is now essentially empty. I have tried showing hidden files and/or cache with no luck.

Here is a screenshot of df -h:

[image: screenshot of PuTTY showing the output of df -h]

Comment: Did you empty the trash?

Comment: Please run `df -h` in the guest and add it to your question.

Comment: I tried that using the following command rm -rf /var/www/html/Trash/* but it says the folder does not exist. Is there another command I can use? I can't see any folders in the share, not even hidden folders so maybe my path is incorrect?

Comment: How did you delete the files? From within the guest or from windows?

Comment: I deleted the files from Windows initially through the Samba Share

Comment: Please, show the output of `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /var/www/`
BTW your **root** partition is full where **var** folder is located. The problem is with partition not directory.

Comment: I tried to add a screenshot but don't get an option for images in comments but here is the result : 4.0K    /var/www/html
8.0K    /var/www/
and that's all that comes through. Okay I see what you mean regarding / and I didn't initially pick that up. I think I need to redo the virtual machine and bind /var/www/ to a partition and share that

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, you need to find out what's using your space. Start with

```
du -sk  /!(+(boot|run|dev|sys))/ 2>/dev/null
```

That may take some time to complete

For the largest directory, drill down into it: assuming /var

```
du -sk /var/*/ 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: `/tmp` is often guilty.

Comment: Aah okay this is really helpful thank you! I am going to redo my virtual machine and seperate my /var/www and keep an eye on that /tmp folder so hopefully I won't run into these annoying scenarios again!! Thanks guys much appreciated! M. Dm pointed out something really obvious that I overlooked and that was that / was being affected and I was looking at /var/www/html because that is what is being displayed in Windows as full so that was a really silly oversight from my side

Comment: No doubts we have are silly, guy. They are useful for  learning! :)